# ServiceStack proper way to access routes and avoid markup

Tags: asp.net, web-services, servicestack

I think this question is more about best practices regarding web services and not necessarily limited to ServiceStack only. From what I've read here and on the SS wiki, the 'recommended' way to implement parent-child entities is to break them down via routes.

For example:

```
/Users/{UserID}
/Users/{UserID}/Entities
```

Where User is the logged on user, and entities are his/her items. I'm implementing jqueryui autocomplete and here is where I'm suspecting I'm not doing the right thing.

In the script the path needs the Userid, so I have to manually render it in the browser so that it reads:

```
type: "GET",
url: "svc/users/**8**/entities",
data: { "SearchTerm": request.term, "Format": 'json' },
```

This smells wrong to me. I have the UserID from the session and I can get it that way. So I wonder if there a better way to access these objects without having to render data directly into markup?

Am I doing this wrong?

On a side note: I know I could place this data in a hidden field and access it via script etc, I am just curious if there is a better/recommended way to do this via sessions while keeping the routes as is.

Comment: I think the logged in user is a special case. You should be getting this information, as you say, from another part of the request. I prefer sticking authorization info in the headers, but if you have it in the session that also works.

Comment: So should the routes remain the same or should I now just make the simpler to something like Users/Entities and in the request I set the userid from the Session? This sounds more like what I should be doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally this is done with another endpoint, Facebook for instance, uses `/my/`, but you could do what ever you want.

The reason being, it's very likely you will be returning different information for a user about themselves than you share about that user with someone else.

Let's pretend `/user/{UserId}/books` returns a user's favorite books. If I want to know what someone's favorite books are, I might be interested in the title, and a brief description, but if I want to see (and possibly manage) my list of favorite books then I might want more information, like the day I added the favorite book, or friends of mine that also like the book.

so `/user/{UserId}/books` returns:

```
{
    "books":[
         { "title":"Hary Potter", "desc":"A boy who is magic..." }
    ]
}
```

however `/my/books` returns:

```
{
    "books":[
         {
              "title":"Harry Potter",
              "desc":"A boy who is magic...",
              "friensWhoLikeBook":[
                  { "id":1234, "name":"Bob" }
              ],
              "personalCommentsAboutBookNotToBeShared":"This book changed my life..."
          }
     ]
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, /my, /self etc  is probably the best way to implement this.